# Как убрать лишние пробелы?

Tags: c++

Под лишними пробелами понимается два и более пробелов в подряд. Вот мой код: `

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    cout<<"Введите строку:"<<endl<<endl;
    string str, pstr;
    getline(cin, str);
    int x = sizeof(str);
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        x = str.find(' ');
        pstr = str.erase(x, x);
    }
    cout<<"Результат: "<<str<<endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int x = sizeof(str);` - что по-вашему делает этот код?

Comment: x = str.find(' ');pstr = str.erase(x, x); на if(str[i]==' ' && str[i+1]==' '){str.erase(x,x);i--;} должно более менее заработать

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков Код - в ответы, советы -  в комментарии. У вас наоборот ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регулярные выражения. Они решают все проблемы. Или удваивают их.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main(){
    std::string str = "   What    is your  name?  ";
    std::cout << std::regex_replace(str, std::regex(" {2,}"), " ");
}
```

http://cpp.sh/2lbwr

Answer (score 2):

Вы неучли некоторые факты, 
 `pstr = str.erase(x, x);` неправильно, а нужно
  `pstr = str.erase(x + 1, 1);` тоесть вы  стираете следующий пробел, но я убрал всего один, так как не знаю сколько их. Поэтому это тоже неправильно...
Можно например так:

```
std::string s("you    can   do  this     for       example");
    std::istringstream is(s);
    std::string t, res;
    while (is >> t)
        res += t + ' ';
    std::cout << res;
```

вот и ваш результат.

Comment: мне кажется что этот код и переводы строки сотрёт

Answer (score 2):

```
str.erase(
  std::unique(str.begin(), str.end(), 
    [](const char &a, const char &b) { return &a == &b || (a == ' ' && b == ' '); }),
  str.end());
```

Comment: Проверка `&a == &b`, по моему, лишняя

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb: Это вопрос, который меня мучает до сих пор. Стандарт требует, чтобы предикат задавал *отношение эквивалентности*. То есть в том числе `pr(a, a)` должно быть `true`. Мой предикат без `&a == &b` будет заведомо нарушать это требование. Это нехорошо. Передача параметров по ссылке и проверка `&a == &b` - это моя попытка как можно лучше соблюсти это требование хотя бы для lvalues. Но мне до сих пор не ясны границы этот требования. Это - тема для отдельного вопроса. "На практике", работает и без  `&a == &b` (что ожидаемо), но осадочек все равно остается...

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb: Кстати, точно по теме https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708446/stdunique-example-with-no-equivalence-relationship-remove-consecutive-spaces

Comment: Вот я теперь тоже задумался. С разработчиков станется написать `assert(pr(*begin, *begin));`

Answer (score 1):

Ради развлечения :) - можно пройтись посимвольно:

```
auto dst = str.begin();
auto last = *dst;
for(auto src = str.begin(); src != str.end(); last = *src++)
{
    if (*src != last || last != ' ')
    {
        *dst++ = *src;
    }
}
str.erase(dst,str.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

Создай парсер через fstream. И переписывай посимвольно файл. Если предыдущий символ пробел и текущий то не переписывай текущий символ.

Comment: Вы забыли добавить "и текущий символ также пробел".  С другой стороны посимвольное переписывание строки не самое быстрое дело.

Comment: с чего бы? посимвольное переписывание насколько мне известно в ассемблере это 4-6 команд на символ, что очень быстро.

Comment: Если бы только этим все ограничивалось...

Comment: так а что ещё то? даже копию не надо создавать можно прямо исходную строку править