# Работа с текстом c++

Tags: c++

Задан текст. Удалить из него “лишние” пробелы, т.е. из нескольких подряд идущих пробелов оставить только один.

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот ответ на вопрос, там довольно подробно написано: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1355845/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как убрать лишние пробелы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772181/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Быстро и просто, путем переписывания символов "по месту".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string s = " hello, world    is me      Mario!";

  cout << s << '\n';
  int j = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
    if (!(s[i] == ' ' && s[i + 1] == ' '))
      s[j++] = s[i];
  }
  s.resize(j);
  
  cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Компилируем, запускаем и смотрим

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ g++ ttt.cpp && ./a.out
 hello, world    is me      Mario!
 hello, world is me Mario!
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

Comment: Вам тоже спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Первая же ссылка в гугле по запросу "Задан текст. Удалить из него “лишние” пробелы, т.е. из нескольких подряд идущих пробелов C++" - https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1319339.html

Comment: Ладно спасибо. Просто думал что найдется кто-то с более креативным решением.

Comment: @ViacheslavShurygin что это вообще должно значить?

Answer (score 1):

Если нет особых требований к скорости работы алгоритма, то вот как вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a = "hello   world    is      me      Mario!";
    int spaces = 0;
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << "length = " << a.size() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if (a[i] == ' ') {
            int k = i + 1;
            while (k < a.size()) {
                if (a[k] == ' ') {
                    k++;
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (k - i > 1) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j + (k - i) - 1 < a.size(); j++) {
                    a[j] = a[j + (k - i) - 1];
                }
                spaces += (k - i) - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    a.resize(a.size() - spaces);
    cout << endl << a << endl;
    cout << "length = " << a.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Скорости работы не проблема. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот еще:

```
std::istringstream is(s);   
string res;
while (is >> s)
    res += s + ' ';
res.pop_back();
s = res;
```